# Screen freezes on MacBook Pro 2008

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

Today, my screen froze suddenly, and since the I have this problem reoccurring in certain intervals. I ran /sbin/fsck -fy and got the following results. I assume this is something with the processor? Would be nice if someone could help me out here.

[image]

I have to say that I have a bad battery, but as long as it is plugged in, it shouldn't be a problem?

Also, i unfortunately dont have the hardware diagnosis dvd and cant get it to run by holding down d.

Comment: I got a suggestion tht this mig be the harddrive. I tried another ssd, but the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. It was one of the RAM slots that caused the problem. After removing one of the RAM chips everything runs fine and stable for over a week now.